create chart in ms excel with formulas, filtered by several colums and rows
I need help creating a graph in MS Excel, with the average age (male and female), by country and for each event. For the event, I would like to add a combobox to be able to filter the type of event. To know if I participated in the event, the cell must contain the value 1, if it has no value, you did not participate.
This is my excel data:

I tried with excel formulas, but no luck :(

Get your data into a normalized structure, then format that normalized table into an Excel table using CTRL + t. Then insert a pivot table.

tk bugdrown, thats what id did.. it worked ..
